# searching datas in the database with prepare statement

Tags: php, html

a quick question :), I wrote this because someone said that my codes are vulnerable to mysql injection and it is a requirement to learn prepared statement in web programming to avoid any user putting malicious data or statement into the database..What I have is a search function that search data from the database, if you type in a string like this "torres" then i search for torres but if you just put "tor" it won't search for datas that contain "tor" in their name..I don't know the correct format while using prepared statement, If you have advice I'm very happy to take it :)

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

    $box = $_POST['box'];
    $box = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$box);
    $grade =$_POST['grade'];
    $section = $_POST['section'];
    $strand = $_POST['strand'];




      $sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE fname LIKE ? or lname LIKE ? or mname LIKE ? or grade = ? or track = ? or section = ?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
            echo "SQL FAILED";
        }
        else {
            //bind the parameter place holder
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss",$box, $box, $box, $grade, $strand, $section);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['lname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['fname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['mname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['grade']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['track']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['section']."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
        }

        }
```

Comment: `$box = "%{$_POST['box']}%";` You just forgot the wildcards.

Comment: I would suggest adding them when doing the binding, otherwise if you check `$box` it now has the wildcards fused with it. `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss",'%'.$box.'%', '%'.$box.'%', '%'.$box.'%', $grade, $strand, $section);`  Also you may not want to do a "contains" search on every field that uses it.

Comment: Another way to do this would be to make a full text index in the DB that uses all 3 fields, and then use `Match Against`.  But that's probably a bit more advanced.  The thing it would do is allow you to search all 3 fields at the same time.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix full text search is the king's way. On variable handling DRY priciple is preferable.

Comment: To be honest I didn't realize there was 3 of them at first ... :/

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Why not just make that your answer? Or the slightly simpler `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssss', "%$box%", "%$box%", "%$box%", $grade, $strand, $section)`?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I clearly prefer the king's way. This should be your primary answer showing an example/explaination. That's quality what SO needs. String interpolation/concatenation can be done by every beginner. Full text search is worth to be an answer.

Comment: I have no problem in full text search hehe, but if I chose grade 12, ICT, B then click submit it doesn't search anything, then someone told me to put an "AND" instead of or but it doesn't wok..I'm a beginner in php

Comment: @dread - there I added a fix for that for you, it's pretty strait forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested:

> @ArtisticPhoenix I clearly prefer the king's way [compound full text index]. This should be your primary answer showing an example/explaination.

First make a full text index that includes all three fields (this is in PHPmyAdmin, it's a bit easier to explain with an image)

[image]

Then do a query like this:

```
#PDO version SELECT * FROM `temp` WHERE MATCH(fname,mname,lname)AGAINST(:fullname IN BOOLEAN MODE)
#MySqli version SELECT * FROM `temp` WHERE MATCH(fname,mname,lname)AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)
SELECT * FROM `temp` WHERE MATCH(fname,mname,lname)AGAINST('edward' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

[image]

It seems simple but there are some things with full text to be aware of   Min char count which is 3 (I think) anything smaller than that is not searched on.  This can be changed but it requires repairing the DB and restarting MySql.

Stop words, these are things like `and`, `the` etc.  These can also be configured in my.cnf.

Punctuation is ignored.  This might not seem a big deal on names but think of hyphenated last names.

Usually I reduce the word min to 2 and point the stopwords to an empty file (disabling them).

The match against syntax is quite different, it's pretty powerful but it's not really used outside of full text.  An example is: this is the wild card `*` and you use `'"'` double quotes for exact phrase match `'"match exactly"'`, and `+` is *logical* AND, such as `word+ word+` (default is or), `-` is do not match this etc...  If I remember right, I used it a bunch a few years ago but haven't had to use it recently.

For example doing "begins with" on a partial word

```
SELECT * FROM `temp` WHERE MATCH(fname,mname,lname)AGAINST('edwar*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Same result matches one row.  The obvious benefit is searching all 3 fields at the same time, but the full text syntax itself can be quite useful too.

For more information:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

PS. I might add that using `OR` in a query can really kill performance, I've went as far as to replace simple `OR` with a `UNION` because of how bad the performance is on a large table.  Logically the DB optimizer has to rescan the entire table for an `OR`, unlike `AND` where it can use the result of the previous expression to reduce the next expressions data set (or that is how I understand it).   I can say the performance difference is very noticeable using OR vs UNION.

This is true for a compound full text index vs doing OR on each field separately.  By default fulltext is faster, but it's even faster this way.

## To fix your current query (for the sake of completeness)

You need whats known as an exclusive or, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE ( fname LIKE ? OR lname LIKE ? OR mname LIKE ? ) AND grade = ? AND track = ? AND section = ?
```

What this does is group the OR's together so that they evalute as one expression to the "next level up" ( outside the parenthesis ).  Basically order of operations.  In English, you would have to match at least 1 of these columns `fname`, `lname`, `mname` AND you would also have to match all of the rest of the columns as well, to get a result returned for any given row.

- If you use all `OR` (as you are now) and any single field matches, then the query comes back as true with matches.  Which is the behaviour you are experiencing now.
- If you simply change everything outside of the name fields to `AND`, Basically remove the parenthesis

Like this:

```
 #this is wrong don't use it.
 SELECT * FROM student WHERE fname LIKE ? OR lname LIKE ? OR mname LIKE ? AND grade = ? AND track = ? AND section = ?
```

Then you have to match this way.

```
 (grade AND track AND section AND mname) OR lname OR fname
```

So if the last or first name match you get results regardless of any of the other fields.  But the `mname` field you would find has to match with all the rest of the fields to get a result (but you would not likely notice this).  Because, it would seem that the query works how you want but only when the `mname` is a match.

I hope that makes sense.  It may be helpful to think of the WHERE clause as an IF condition the same logic rules apply.

Cheers!

Comment: Why are my answers so long :/

Comment: thanks for this, I may be doing this in my other functions, I'm new to php and database and I'm bulding a website that creates student schedule and update students information including their sections and stuff.. thanks for the respond..but adding parenthesis is not working in my code at all..my general plan is that if someone chooses to see the grade level, strand, and section they're going to select in the dropdown button but selecting one like grade is working but if I select all(in 3 select dropdown) like grade 12, ICT, B it won't search even if that data is present in the database

Comment: If you have PHPmyAdmin it may be helpful to build the query in there and then move it to PHP, that way you know the query works.  This is something I still do after 8+ years.

Comment: Yes I'm am doing it just to check :)

Comment: That way if you have a working query, then you know that the PHP code is at fault.  Process of elimination is your best friend in debugging (well besides error reporting).